# Local python package install doesn't copy package any more?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

This used to work but I don't know what changed; nothing has changed in this repo for a while.

I have a local python package that I want to install via `pip`.  My source tree looks like:

```
./local_packages/my-package-0.0.3.tar.gz
```

and my requirements.txt has only

```
my-package
```

I run

```
pip install --find-links="./local_packages" --target=./python_modules/ -r requirements.txt
```

This finds my package and installs it in `python_modules` but I can't import it:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Nov 30 2020, 14:15:49) 
[GCC Apple LLVM 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from my_package import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

When I look in `python_modules` I see all of the dependencies of `my-package` as well as `my_package-0.0.3-py3.6.egg-info/` but there is no module for just `my_package`.

If I downgrade pip from 20.3 to 19.3.1, then I see what I was expecting, with both a folder for .egg-info as well as for the module itself.  My import works correctly etc.

Is this expected behavior?  Am I missing something?

Comment: what exactly is `my-package-0.0.3`? Would be helpful to know if people want to reproduce to help you out

Comment: It's' a local package we authored ourselves with some common stuff.  But it really could be any package that is on the local filesystem and not in the registry.

Comment: The deleted answer noting a number of issues with the resolver in 20.3 is an interesting data point... this didn't break prior to 20.3.